# Unable to backup the databases

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, database-backups

While trying to backup my database using the command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p root --all-databases > /var/www/html/temp/karooka.sql
```

all I get is the following in the sql dump:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The password should be along with -p option  `mysqldump -u root -proot` or if you are using the command on CLI then just `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /var/www/html/temp/karooka.sql` then enter it will ask you enter the password.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify the password in the command, use

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /var/www/html/temp/karooka.sql
```

and enter the password when prompted.